# Passing a websocket via props in ReactJS send function is not recognised

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I've been trying to pass a websocket down to children via props, going off of this tutorial:
https://dev.to/finallynero/using-websockets-in-react-4fkp

passing the websocket like this from the parent

```
render() {
    return <MIDIComponent websocket={this.state.ws} />;
  }
```

Then getting and using it like this

```
const websocket = this.props;

function getMIDIMessage(msg) {
      websocket.send(
        JSON.stringify({ message: Array.from(msg.data), type: "config" })
      );
```

this is all contained with a function with a bunch of other stuff which is then called from within `componentDidMount()`

When I do this I get the error

`Uncaught TypeError: websocket.send is not a function`

doing this results in websocket being undefined

```
const {websocket} = this.props;
```

EDIT:

The websocket is being created like this:

`var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws/assistant/user/");`

The server is definitely connected, copying this line directly into my child component and opening the websocket directly in there makes it work and allows me to send data to the server, which makes me wonder if I should just do it like this. BUT I'm going to be using the websocket a few times throughout the App, so it feels right to only initialize it once and pass it wherever it needs to go.

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: Do `const {websocket} = this.props;` or `const websocket = this.props.websocket;`

Comment: whats  `this.state.ws` & u sure its connected to server ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, both of those result in ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of null``` I don't know if it matters but getMIDIMessage is registered as a callback which gets called whenever a MIDI message is received in a designated MIDI port using the Web MIDI API.

Comment: can you provide minimal reproducible example

Comment: and is still please add, websocket init code in above example

Comment: yeah the server is connected, Its django channels I've got it working using purely django just trying to move the front end over to react. ```this.state.ws``` is the websocket, created exactly as in the tutorial linked. I've not changed much other than adding the MIDI stuff in and calling it from inside componentDidMount()

Comment: I may just double check its actually connecting the websocket

Comment: yeah definitely connected and websocket works normally, just not passed this way. Question edited

Answer (score 0):

OK so I solved the problem.

It was partly my own stupidity - First I was creating the websocket component as WebSocket, which obviously clashes with the WebSocket() function.

Then when inside the child setting up everything inside componentDidMount() I was neglecting to pass 'this' down into the functions I was calling there, so getting to this.props was not possible. It's now working.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const that = this;
    this.setupMIDI(that);
  }
```